# Getting syntax error when restoring sql server database via pyspark

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to execute a database restore in an aws glue job, I get syntax error when running the below query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname FROM DISK = '/tmp/database.bak'
```

An error occurred while calling o79.load. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RESTORE'.

I've also tried running the restore script inside an exec, but I get syntax error near the keyword 'EXEC' when trying that.

Is this because I can only query tables through spark, and I can't do things like database restores?

My spark code is as follows:

```
df = sql_context.read.jdbc(
    url=url,
    table="RESTORE DATABASE db_name FROM DISK = '/tmp/local_file_name.bak'",
    properties=jdbc_source['properties'],
)
```

Comment: `spark.read.jdbc` is used to read data from sql databases, so why are you trying to restore your sql server db from Spark? Restore it in your sql server environment then use spark to read some table.

Comment: I'm going to be getting a large number of backups and looking at automatically reading them into RDS once they land in S3. From here I'll be loading the data into Redshift. I don't want to be manually restoring each one at a time.

Comment: Then you can look for some scripting solutions but it's definitely not a task for spark.

Comment: `sql_context.read.` <=== why do you expect this context to be able to write/execute?

Comment: Care to elaborate on what you mean by 'scripting solutions'?

Comment: I agree, sql_context.read doesn't seem appropriate. But sqlcontext.sql doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you say this was an AWS RDS instance? Have you tried using `msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database` instead? Ref: [Restoring a database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore)

Comment: This too will require that I submit an exec command. I'm going to just create a connection with pyodbc. I thought it might have been easier to connect with Glue but clearly not. I'll give the rds_restore_database command a try via pyodbc, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to use Spark in the end for this, I'm instead going to use the python pyodbc library since that way I can execute all SQL commands.